# Can't install apollo/client in nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo-client

I can't install apollo/client in my Nuxtjs2 project. How can I fix this?

When I run command:

```
npm install @apollo/client
```

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: nuxt-app@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: graphql-ws@4.9.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql-ws
npm ERR!   graphql-ws@"^4.4.1" from @graphql-tools/url-loader@6.10.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@graphql-tools/url-loader
npm ERR!     @graphql-tools/url-loader@"^6.2.4" from graphql-tools@6.2.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/graphql-tools
npm ERR!       graphql-tools@"^6.0.9" from vue-cli-plugin-apollo@0.22.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-apollo
npm ERR!         vue-cli-plugin-apollo@"^0.22.2" from @nuxtjs/apollo@4.0.1-rc.5
npm ERR!         node_modules/@nuxtjs/apollo
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @apollo/client@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: graphql-ws@5.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql-ws
npm ERR!   peerOptional graphql-ws@"^5.5.5" from @apollo/client@3.7.15
npm ERR!   node_modules/@apollo/client
npm ERR!     @apollo/client@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Comment: Hi Eflyax, is this resolved for you? Try uninstalling graphql-ws and use "graphql" instead!